# passing data from data set to a dictionary

Tags: c#

Basically I have a data set with some data a data base table, I want to pass the data to a dictionary, what could be a good way yo accomplish my goal. Assuming that the dictionary have this structure

```
Dictionary<int,string>
```

I'm looking for some method to bind the rows of the dataset with the key and value of the dictionary.

Comment: Beyond loop and add? (which is basically what the LINQ .ToDictionary(...)` does, too)

Comment: exactly something beyond that loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, if your dataset implements IEnumerable or IQueryable you can use the ToDictionary extension method:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = data.ToDictionary(e => e.id, e => e.name);
```

Comment: can you give me an example about how can i make the implementation of the interface